# Selecting different options from multiple dropdown menus in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Let's say I have 3 single-select dropdown menus (color, width, and height). Is there a way to select an option from the first two dropdown menus and have the highchart update based on the dual selection? For example, if I selected red from the first dropdown (color) and 2 inches from the second dropdown (width), is there a way for the chart to include both of these elements with the third dropdown (height) staying at the default value? On the flip side, I should be able to only select "red" from the color dropdown and have the rest of the dropdowns return to their default. Is this possible? Right now, I can only write else/if statements based on one list selection not 2 and greater.

I'm very new to programming, so if you could provide a simple example, that would be great!

Comment: Can you paste the code with what you have tried? Besides, I selected red color, what is the action then? What is the factor that makes the chart update with the selected color + default values and what is the factor that makes the chart wait for selection another parameter by a user?

Comment: From a user experience perspective, consider carefully how you want the "return to default" action to occur. Yes, you can use multiple menus to affect aspects of a Highcharts visualization. If you want to include/exclude the options in a specific menu, I'd consider also adding a checkbox next to each. If the user leaves the checkbox unchecked, the chart would simply revert to the default value for that option. However, once they check it, it would pick up whatever value is currently selected in that menu. As @morganfree noted, if you have some code to start with, I can help suggest a solution.